# Cookies info Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, rubygems

I'm using cookies in my application (RoR) and I'll have some info about it in my start page (some window with some info text and button accept or not). Have you some tutorials or may be nice gem to do it?

Comment: IMO your question is somewhat unclear. Maybe you can be more specific. Meanwhile you could read: http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/cookies.html

Comment: I'll add sth like this [link](http://polkowski.com.pl/) - some window in mainpage about that this website is using cookies and button accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of you comment, one solution would be the use of - for example - jQuery to build a [modal form](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).
jQuery was the first JavaScript library that came to my mind, you could use any other (like [MooTools](http://mootools.net/forge/browse/tag/modal) or [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/panel/panel-form.html)). Just pick your favorite one :)

To implement this in Rails, have a look onto [this gem](https://github.com/dei79/jquery-modal-rails)

Comment: I thought about jQuery but i don't know how to implement it into RoR

Comment: I added another link to the answer that could help you implement the modal with jQuery&Rails